# Ansible Error: 'list object' has no attribute 'name' when using read_csv module

Tags: ansible

As said in the title, 'list object' has no attribute 'name' error comes up when I try to read from a csv file, and only want to read the "name" column.

my csv:

```
name,uid,gid,password
eg1,1,2,password
eg2,1,2,password
```

I followed from the official Ansible documentation.

my ansible playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: read from CSV
      read_csv:
        path: user-creation.csv
      register: users

    - debug:
        msg: "{{users.list.name}}"
```

the error that I got:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'name'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/ansible/main.yml': line 12, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}
```

I have googled everywhere and it seemed like most people either don't use this module, or they don't have this problem when using the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

```
- name: read from CSV
  read_csv:
    path: user-creation.csv
  register: users

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.name }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ users.list }}"
```

Output:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'eg1', 'uid': '1', 'gid': '2', 'password': 'password'}) => {
    "msg": "eg1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'eg2', 'uid': '1', 'gid': '2', 'password': 'password'}) => {
    "msg": "eg2"
```

On a side note; if you're really stuck with tasks like these, you can use e.g. `awk` to achieve your goal.

Comment: ah, but I just wanted to print out for 'name'.
example:
'eg1', 'eg2'

Comment: That is exactly what it does. It prints eg1, then it prints eg2. That is the msg it returns. Vladimir his answer is correct tho.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter). The task below

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ users.list|json_query('[*].name') }}"
```

gives

```
"msg": [
    "eg1", 
    "eg2"
]
```